# Mask Sentinel 1 images for radar shadow in Colab?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am trying to export Sentinel 1 images from Colab to Google Drive, but before I want to mask out areas of radar shadow and layover. Is there code or a function for masking out radar shadow in the Python API of GEE?

In the code editor I was able to find a set of functions to use a DEM to compare viewing angles to the surface angle to create layers 'shadow' and 'layover' and then update masks to mask out areas of radar shadow and layover:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/263ca05ec7e63077f4a1992c8fd1c261

Here is the code where I am trying to adapt that JavaScript into Python.

```py
# Earth Engine Python API
!earthengine authenticate
import ee
ee.Initialize()
import math 
from IPython.display import Image

image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD/S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20180321T140714_20180321T140739_021114_02447B_B0FC')
##Now I want to preprocess this image using adapted Javascript from the link I posted below, but since I am very new to both languages/programming am having trouble
# Implementation by Andreas Vollrath (ESA), inspired by Johannes Reiche (Wageningen)
def preProcess(image):
  return maskOverlay(
      terrainCorrection(image)
    )
def maskOverlay(image):
  return image.updateMask(
      image.select('layover').and(image.select('shadow')) 
##issue 1: the python API won't let me use .and is there an equivalent 
#function in python?
  )
def terrainCorrection(image):
  imgGeom = image.geometry()
  srtm = ee.Image('JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30_V1_1').clip(imgGeom) # 30m srtm 
  sigma0Pow = ee.Image.constant(10).pow(image.divide(10.0))

  # Article ( numbers relate to chapters)
  # 2.1.1 Radar geometry 
  theta_i = image.select('angle')
  phi_i = ee.Terrain.aspect(theta_i)\
                           .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), theta_i.get('system:footprint'), 1000)\
                           .get('aspect')

  # 2.1.2 Terrain geometry
  alpha_s = ee.Terrain.slope(srtm).select('slope')
  phi_s = ee.Terrain.aspect(srtm).select('aspect')

  # 2.1.3 Model geometry
  # reduce to 3 angle
  phi_r = ee.Image.constant(phi_i).subtract(phi_s)

  # convert all to radians
  phi_rRad = phi_r.multiply(math.pi/180)
  alpha_sRad = alpha_s.multiply(math.pi/180)
  theta_iRad = theta_i.multiply(math.pi/180)
  ninetyRad = ee.Image.constant(90).multiply(math.pi/180)

  # slope steepness in range (eq. 2)
  alpha_r = (alpha_sRad.tan().multiply(phi_rRad.cos())).atan()

  # slope steepness in azimuth (eq 3)
  alpha_az = (alpha_sRad.tan().multiply(phi_rRad.sin())).atan()

  #local incidence angle (eq. 4)
  theta_lia = (alpha_az.cos().multiply((theta_iRad.subtract(alpha_r)).cos())).acos()
  theta_liaDeg = theta_lia.multiply(180/math.pi)
  # 2.2 
  # Gamma_nought_flat
  gamma0 = sigma0Pow.divide(theta_iRad.cos())
  gamma0dB = ee.Image.constant(10).multiply(gamma0.log10())
  ratio_1 = gamma0dB.select('VV').subtract(gamma0dB.select('VH'))

  # Volumetric Model
  nominator = (ninetyRad.subtract(theta_iRad).add(alpha_r)).tan()
  denominator = (ninetyRad.subtract(theta_iRad)).tan()
  volModel = (nominator.divide(denominator)).abs()

  # apply model
  gamma0_Volume = gamma0.divide(volModel)
  gamma0_VolumeDB = ee.Image.constant(10).multiply(gamma0_Volume.log10())

  # we add a layover/shadow maskto the original implmentation
  # layover, where slope > radar viewing angle 
  alpha_rDeg = alpha_r.multiply(180/math.pi)
  layover = alpha_rDeg.lt(theta_i);

  # shadow where LIA > 90
  shadow = theta_liaDeg.lt(85);

  # calculate the ratio for RGB vis
  ratio = gamma0_VolumeDB.select('VV').subtract(gamma0_VolumeDB.select('VH'))

  output = gamma0_VolumeDB.addBands(ratio).addBands(alpha_r).addBands(phi_s).addBands(theta_iRad)\
                              .addBands(layover).addBands(shadow).addBands(gamma0dB).addBands(ratio_1)

  return image.addBands(
    output.select(['VV', 'VH', 'slope_1', 'slope_2'], ['VV', 'VH', 'layover', 'shadow']), 
    None, 
    False
  )
######Done with preprocessing code

image_post = preProcess(image)
Image(url = image_post.select('VV').getThumbUrl({'min': -40, 'max': 40, 'dimensions': 512*2}))
bandNames = image.bandNames()
print('Band names: ', bandNames.getInfo())
```

When I now look at the image it doesn't seem to be masked and I can't see bands 'layover' and 'shadow'. Maybe because I had to comment out the .and part of the overlay code?

I am very new to both languages and programming in general. What am I missing here both to 1) the .and issue in Python and 2) to why this processing code, even when I run it all (commenting out the .and second part of maskoverlay), still doesn't mask out areas of shadow and layover in my image or generate those bands?

Input: 1 GEE image in Colab

Preferred output: 1 GEE image in Colab with new bands 'layover' and 'shadow' that I could use to mask out areas of radar shadow.

Comment: Hi Zach, please see the [guide on posting Earth Engine questions](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help#gis-stack-exchange). It's important to have a specific code question and make your script reproducible. That means you either need to share all assets used in your script or mock up an example that reproduces the issue. Since your question is more about method selection, I'd start with the [Earth Engine developer group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-earth-engine-developers). There are quite a few active S1 users there.

Comment: This post might be relevant: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-earth-engine-developers/radar$20shadow%7Csort:date/google-earth-engine-developers/lb0emrrmHzg/QUH2YiYACgAJ

Comment: Hey Justin, that link says it is a banned group due to offensive content? Not sure what that means.

Comment: Also I think I have added specific code. Should I repost this question since this one has been closed? It took me a while to reduce my code down to the minimum form to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sounds good. I will hang tight then.